# Assigning User Roles not processing

Tags: acl, roles

I created a user role and operations.
I tried assigning a group (access based) to the user role in the assignment section. It does not stick. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. The role is set up as well as the operations. The group has the correct access checked off. 
Advice? 
Working on Drupal 7 and on the last 4.7 CiviCRM.
[image]

Comment: Hi Danielle - setting up ACLs can be tricky the first few times as there are so many steps to work through, and some of them can seem like you do the same thing in several places. I would suggest you summarise the steps you took based on https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/ and see if you can spot either where you might have missed a step, or where you are certain you took a step but it is not working. Other option is to set something up on the demo site so someone else can look over it (warning it refreshes every 24 hours)

Comment: it would also probably help if you add screenshots for each step of the ACL construction you did.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just wait a week for the new update that @Jon G had mentioned.

Comment: Cool. Sorry to wrongly imply you may not have done all the right steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in CiviCRM 4.7.23 - [CRM-21076](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21076).

If you feel comfortable editing the PHP files, you just need to [add one line](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10866/files) to apply the fix.

Otherwise, hold tight for CiviCRM 4.7.24, which is scheduled for September 6th, 2017.